# Why does a man's witness count as two women's witness in Islam?

Tags: women

Why is it that whenever witnesses are required in Islam, two women are required to take the place of only one man?

The Quran in Sura 2:282 says:

> And let two men from among you bear witness to all such documents
>   [contracts of loans without interest]. But if two men be not
>   available, there should be one man and two women to bear witness so
>   that if one of the women forgets (anything), the other may remind her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sunni point of view, Women have deficiency in reason and in religion. That is why a woman's testimony is accepted if it is supported by another woman.

> "I have not seen anyone more deficient in ability to reason and deen
>   than you. A cautious sensible man can be led astray by some of you.”
>   It was said: “O Allah’s Messenger (peace be upon him)! What is the
>   deficiency in our reasoning and deen?” He said: “Is not the testimony
>   of two women equal to the witness of one man?” It was said: "What is
>   deficient in her deen?" The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: "Is not
>   it true that a woman can neither pray nor fast during her menses?” 
>   [Al-Bukhari]
>
> The Prophet (peace be upon him) explained that the deficiency in
>   woman's reasoning means their weak memory. Therefore, their testimony
>   must be verified and supported by another woman to confirm their
>   testimony, because they may forget and thus add or omit some of the
>   testimony.
>
> As for the deficiency of their religion it means they abandon Salah
>   (prayer) and Sawm (fasting) during their menses and post-partum
>   period. They are not commanded to repeat Salah (prayer). This is the
>   meaning of their being lacking in deen. They will not be called to
>   account for this shortcoming, because it is the will of Allah
>   (Glorified and Exalted be He) Who legislated this for their comfort.
>   If they were to observe Sawm during their menses and postpartum
>   period, it would be difficult for them. Therefore, Allah commands them
>   to abandon Sawm during their menses and post-partum period, and make
>   up for it later. As for Salah, there is something which prevents them
>   from ceremonial purity. Therefore, it is out of the Mercy of Allah
>   (Glorified and Exalted be He) that He commands them to abandon Salah
>   during their menses and postpartum period.
>
> This deficiency does not mean that we cannot rely on her in narration
>   or testimony, if she is supported by another woman. Men being better
>   than women in reasoning and memory is general. Some women may excel
>   men. There are many women whose reason is better than men, and are
>   stronger in deen (Religion) and memorization. The report of the
>   Prophet (peace be upon him) only indicates that the male gender is
>   generally better in reasoning and religion than the female gender in
>   the two aspects specified by the Prophet (peace be upon him). Women
>   may perform more righteous deeds than men, their piety may be more
>   than men, and thus their rank in the Hereafter may be better than the
>   rank of men.  [1](http://www.alifta.com/Fatawa/FatawaChapters.aspx?View=Page&PageID=361&PageNo=1&BookID=14)

This is the explanation of the Scholars : [Deficiency of women in Deen and reason](http://www.alifta.com/Fatawa/FatawaChapters.aspx?View=Page&PageID=361&PageNo=1&BookID=14)

In fact, one of the scholars of Islam and second most highest narrator of hadeeths was Aisha (Radiallahu anha), who was a woman.

Now, most non-Muslims might think of this as a backward view. So, I want to give some logical and medical reports to support this view. So, I request them to give a patient reading with open mind and prevent emotions come in the way of their reasoning.

Please read this article which cites some medical reports and provides some reasoning : 
[Why two witnesses?](http://www.sunnahonline.com/ilm/dawah/0030.htm)

Thank you.

Comment: This a good answer, although this answer will be very hard to swallow for us in the West since we are taught that women and men are equal in every respect. I would add the phrase from Surah aali-Imran: "And the male is not like the female" [3:36].  Also, just because Men may have a degree above men in terms of reasoning/deen, this doesn't make them inherently better.  What makes someone better over another in Islam is piety (taqwa)

Comment: The last the paragraphs suggesting that women have inferior mental functions seems pretty conclusively false; perhaps the people on [cogsci.se] can clear this up for you.

Comment: This is not a correct answer and it portrays Islam falsely and negatively. May Allah forgive you @Abdullah.

Comment: @Jammooly Explain how it does that. This answer correctly describes the balance of Islam and it justifies the actual roles of men and women and how different they are from each other.

Comment: @Stranger, there isn't any credible scientific evidence that proves women are more deficient than men in intellect and reason.

Comment: @Stranger Also, You should read my answer on this post. If you believe the women are deficient in intellect and reason, then you'll be going against the Quranic evidence and evidence in hadith transmission.

Comment: @Stranger, This hadith by Prophet Muhammad (SAW) is expressing his view about the women that lived in his time period and society. This isn't a universal, timeless application to label all women like this.

Check out this link: https://hawramani.com/is-the-hadith-mentioning-women-as-deficient-in-intelligence-and-faith-authentic/

Comment: @Jammooly There doesn't have to be a scientific reason for this. The Hadith is universal as the Prophet (PBUH) specified "women". It applies to all women of all times. The religion and the Hadith are all universal for all times unless specified in them or by scholars. This is the same reason that women aren't allowed to lead nationns in Islam. Islam is a patriarchal religion and there should be no shame in admitting that, unless you are an apologetic.

Comment: @Jammooly Moreover, science doesn't prove that women have less intelligence than men but it does prove that they have an extremely high emotions. It does prove that a lot of decisions women make are based upon their emotions, and there is no problem in that. It's just nature, that's how Allah made them, and based on how he made them, he defined their roles, responsibilites, and limits, and he did the same for men.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140712/discussion-between-jammooly-and-stranger).

Comment: @Jammooly My account just got suspended, what happened?

Comment: @Jammooly It says " your account is suspended on the parent site and cannot chat for 1 day 8 hours."

Comment: I don't know. Inshallah the issue gets resolved soon.

Comment: @Jammooly Insha Allah, I received your chat notification, I also had a great time talking. Once the issue gets solved (It says in one day), I'll be happy to continue the chat. Just ping me if you want. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Review the research on sex difference in memory and intelligence on wiki, which summarizes the current state of knowledge on this, and refutes most if not all of the ideas on deficiency in memory and intelligence stated in this answer. There are variations on specific tests, but clearly no overall female deficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly this is only, as the Quran points out, in the area of business contracts.  Where if two men are not brought then 1 man and two women.  The Quran also points out that this is in regards to the issue of forgetfulness, because the business world isn't the natural place for a women, the women's responsibility lies in taking care of her children and her home, where it is them man's job to go out and work to support the family.  Furthermore as already mentioned two women in regards to business contracts, where if a women in an area of her expertise is to give witness then that witness is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Allah has set a social system in Quran. According to this social system, women do not have to work, they must be fed and kept safe by their families or by the government. The women are not to be independent in the Islamic social system (I don't mean that they are prohibited to be independent, they don't have to. They have right to request shelter from government. They don't need to work. But they can if they want to, it is not prohibited.).

So, in the Islamic social system, women always depends to some others in both economic means and in emotional means. When a person (not necessarily to be woman) is dependent on someone else, he/she starts to think, live and behave as the one he/she depends to. This is a psychological fact.

So, if we consider the worst conditions, a woman witness can be threaten by her family or husband, or just she can feel herself under pressure of the one she depends to. She can hide some of the facts even if she doesn't want to do so.

Of course, there are also different reasons too.
Women are too emotional. They usually exaggerate events. They have a passive role in the society (it is the same in the entire world). They can't easily express their feelings. They more try to take attention compared to men. They actually feel themselves dependent to other people.

Because of all these reasons (and maybe there are more reasons, Allah knows), two women's witness is not enough for clarifying a crime or some other matter. That doesn't mean `1 man = 2 women`, that's just to make the evidence more robust.

Comment: Would like more information on how women "exaggerate events", "have a passive role in society", "can't express their feelings", and try to take attention compared to men. This is mostly contrary to what I have observed. Is this something the Quran indicates women are like?

Comment: I second user83' comment, can you back up that paragraph with something? Also you say women aren't prohibited from being independent and then go on saying that women _are_ always depending on someone, which is it? Can they be independent or not? And am I correct in my understanding that you basically say that women only count less because the society structure teaches it? (Society says you are dependent -> you become dependent, NOT you are dependent -> society is formed based on that)

Answer (score 0):

Quran itself states the reason clearly: "if one of the women forgets (anything), the other may remind her". This is about the way human mind works. Men keep the event in more details. This is about nature and something like a man being physically stronger than a woman. Allah that created human knows it better than any authority. So Quran have to be obeyed and a Muslim should not put questions on words of Allah. Interpretation of all cases is not so simple. We can not disobey a command while we could not find a reason for it.

Comment: _"Men keep the event in more details."_ Do you have any proof for that? A quick search in google actually brings up results how women before their menopause outperform men when it comes to memorisation.

Comment: "Men keep the event in more details."My experience has been that women often keep the details on family activities, social schedules, finances, and participate in decision making while men do their activities. So I think you are just making an unfounded assertion.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Quran 2:82 prescribed two female witnesses to one male witness is for multiple reasons.

### TL;DR

The reason for this witness ruling, which is 2 female witnesses to 1 male witness for commercial transactions is because women at the time and throughout much of history and even in many areas present-day were more familiar with domestic/private sphere of society while men were more familiar with the public/business sphere of society, meaning men were more financially aware. And it should be taken into consideration that a man has the financial burden to provide for his wife and daughters while women have no financial responsibility in Islam. But as we can see in modern times, many women work in the public sphere and are financially aware so they should suffice, alone, in place of one male witness with similar qualifications.

This ruling also protected female witnesses from possible bullying or manipulation. And with many of these contracts lasting for lengthy amounts of time, a female witness, possibly, would not always be available, if there might be a need to review the contract for whatever reason, since they could be busy with taking care of their kids, pregnancy, etc.

In no way does this ayah says or even infers that this witness ruling is because of the false belief that a female is more deficient in reason and intellect than a male.

### The Context of Quran 2:82

Quran 2:82 is the longest Ayah in the Quran. One must read it entirely to understand why the witness ruling was designed this way.

This ayah is said to have been
revealed in connection with agricultural forward sales, but is generally
applicable to all agreements, including loans (Ṭ), where payment and delivery
do not take place simultaneously (IK, Q).

Among the variety of interpretations concerning the stipulation that, if one
cannot find two men to serve as witnesses, one may call two women and one
man, it is acknowledged that this provision is peculiar to the commercial
transactions mentioned in this verse (IK, Q, R, Ṭ) and differs from other kinds of
testimony. **Other verses explicitly equate male and female testimony, such as
24:6–9, where accusations of adultery are given equal consideration whether
they are made by the husband or the wife.** In the classical Islamic legal tradition,
women were generally excluded from bearing witness in cases involving
corporal punishments and qiṣāṣ (see 2:178c), but even in such cases it seems to
be a question of preference, since in the absence of a male witness, women’s
testimony would be accepted (Q). Such preferences likely reflect a general social
aversion to involving women in such matters. Moreover, since cases are
adjudicated by a judge, it is impossible, strictly speaking, to quantify the value of
testimony, and a judge simply needs all the relevant evidence to come to a
decision.

*If one of the two errs, the other can remind her*: “to err” means to forget
some aspect of the contract (Q, R, Ṭ). The commentators have generally hewed
close to two interpretations of this phrase: that by being reminded the erring
woman would become equal, legally, to the man; or that the two women together
were equal, legally, to the man. The latter was more widely accepted. **It is also
true that some commentators, but not all, understood this verse to indicate an
essential inferiority in women’s ability to judge objectively and hence the
intrinsic unreliability of their testimony. Nothing in the verse demands such a
reading, however, and indeed the very structure of the transaction described
indicates otherwise.** This verse could easily describe a situation in which two
female parties arrange a forward sale and bring in two men as witnesses. In
Islamic Law women, like men, can transact any sale or loan on their own behalf,
including any number of transactions where witnesses are not necessary; **thus the
provision for two women to act as witnesses in place of a single man in forward
sales or debts must reflect a different purpose**.

There are no rules about individual women entering into such contracts, but
**since the women of the time, as a general rule, would have been inexperienced
with the particulars of potentially complex financial arrangements, accepting two
women in the place of one man would have been more practical, since the
purpose of such testimony was to ensure the proper observance of the particulars
of the loan or sale. Considering the social conditions of the time, for women to
participate in this way at all would have been itself a major change, and to
require two of them in such transactions can be understood as providing a
measure of protection for them against bullying or manipulation, rather than as
an indictment of their testimony.** Indeed, jurists such as Abū Bakr ibn ʿArabī, in
Aḥkām al-Qur’ān, wondered why a man could not remind one woman if she
erred, and he could not arrive at an answer.

**If one reads this provision for women’s testimony in light of the legally
established principle upholding women’s competence to own property and carry
out economic transactions, it suggests that the stipulation regarding women’s
testimony in the present verse is particular to this circumstance and is meant to
address certain social or communal difficulties a woman might face when
witnessing in such a case.** Unlike spot sales, which require no witnesses or
written contracts, a forward contract involved items requiring a certain level of
expertise to understand. **Indeed, from among those whom you approve as
witnesses suggests that it is a matter of competence in a specific area, and such
transactions would not have been widely carried out by women of the time.
Moreover, such arrangements could extend over years, and women would not
necessarily be as available to act as male witnesses, from a strictly social point
of view, over a long period of time.** The trade of present goods refers to a
transaction where delivery is made at the time of payment and is thus concluded
instantaneously, obviating the need to write a formal contract.

Source: [The Study Quran](https://ia904603.us.archive.org/25/items/the-study-quran_202111/The%20Study%20Quran.pdf) p. 315-318

Extra Links to check out:

- [Women in Islamic Law: Examining Five Prevalent Myths](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/read/paper/women-in-islamic-law-examining-five-prevalent-myths) (Myth 3)
- [Two Minds, The cognitive differences between men and women](https://stanmed.stanford.edu/how-mens-and-womens-brains-are-different)
- [In Islam why are two women witnesses equal to one man’s witness answered by Dr Zakir Naik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apYGWVRWni8)

Answer (score -2):

I think this area is heavily disputed (on witnesses in general).  While the Qu'arn is very clear in your example, it does not explicitly extend that beyond financial matters.

The most commonly accepted reason that I have seen is that financial matters are generally not in the women's sphere of expertise or interests.  On the contrary, many scholars say that a woman's testimony alone is fine on matters that deal with womanly areas, such as child birth.  The number of women can be different depending on the scholar though.

Also, as a wrench in the system, in cases where a husband accuses his wife of unchastity, her testimony will invalidate his.

Comment: "The most commonly accepted reason ...", I've never heard of such a thing that you mentioned.

Comment: Sure, this is not a commonly discussed topic.  You can find a lot of information about this if you read scholars' opinions.  Here is a website that has a large number of them together:
http://www.renaissance.com.pk/septrefl12y2.html

Search for financial, you can find more on your own if that is not enough.

Comment: "it does not explicitly extend that beyond financial matters." whe hadith at issue does not suggest the deficiency if womens' reeason is restricted

Comment: "it does not explicitly extend that beyond financial matters." While the Quran does restrict the deficiency to financial matters, the hadith at issue has the prophet using the deficiency in Quran 2:282 as an example to explain an apparent general deficiency in reasoning.